# Vertical scroll bar works on chrome but does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a model where the buyer is notified about that how many items they have in the cart and they can scroll over the model if the items are overflowing in the model. My problem is that verticle scroll works on chrome and firefox but on chrome, scrollbars are not displayed. I want users to see the scroll bar to make it user-friendly.

```
    <style>
    .product {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .model-body {
        max-height: 350px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

</style>


<div id="custom-popup-model" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" style="color: #c883a3">@*Please take appropriate action*@</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="cartitems-container" style="max-height: 350px; overflow-y: scroll">

        </div>
        @*<a class="btn-primary btn-sm" href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomePage")" style="background: #c883a3">Continue shopping</a>
        <a class="btn-primary btn-sm" href="@Url.RouteUrl("ShoppingCart")" style="background: #c883a3">Proceed To Checkout</a>*@
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" style="background: #c883a3;border-color:#c883a3">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    <script>
  $(function() {

    $("#custom-popup-model").on('show.bs.modal',
      function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/ShoppingCart/FlyoutShoppingCart',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(response) {
            var elements = $(response);
            var found = $('.count', elements);
            $("#modal-title").text(found.text());
            elements.find('.count').remove();


            $("#cartitems-container").append(elements);

          },
          //error: function (response) {
          //    alert(response);
          //}
        });
      }).on('hidden.bs.modal',
      function() {
        $("#cartitems-container").html("");
      });
  })
</script>
```

Here are the result on both Chrome and Firefox.

[image: Chrome]
[image: FireFox]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you please add your url, or code snippet here for better understanding of why it's like that...

Comment: Are you on macOS? If so, macOS is likely responsible for hiding scrollbars (which Firefox refuses to do). You can force them back with some CSS: http://simurai.com/blog/2011/07/26/webkit-scrollbar

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I have added js code too.

Comment: @Greg it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahsan, You just put below css in model-body class.

```
.model-body {overflow-y: scroll;min-height: 100px;}
```